# transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Any idea how to fix this issue? I've had enough rebuilding the project.

```
:app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug FAILED Error:Execution failed for task 
:app:transformClassesWithNewClassShrinkerForDebug. > java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable minifyEnabled in your app build.gradle file:

```
debug {
  minifyEnabled false
  useProguard false
  proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Comment: There is a reason why I'm using shrinking.